# Beyond the Apollo 12 incident, have there been any instances of triggered lightning?

Tags: launch, lightning, apollo-12

As explained in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/1976/16008), the ionised plumes of engine exhausts can provide a low-resistance route for lightning strikes during a launch, potentially endangering the vehicle. This is thought to have been a factor in the Apollo 12 lightning strike which temporarily damaged essential control circuits on board.

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30037/16008) gives some more very thorough detail on the science behind this process and also astutely points out in the comments:

> It might be that the Apollo 12 incident convinced people that *it's not a good idea to launch when there are thunderstorms around.*

**Have there been any other recorded instances of this phenomenon occurring?**

Perhaps the Apollo-12 incident *was* the first recorded occurrence and since then more precaution has been taken with launch conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly, it didn't convince them for long. At least one other vehicle was lost to triggered lightning.

Adding to the misery of the US launch industry in the late 1980s was the [Atlas Centaur 67 incident](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1029/JD094iD11p13169), which was launched into cloudy conditions and subsequently struck by rocket triggered lightning.

> Late in the afternoon of 26 March 1987, while the NRC was still
>   considering whether to review the Theon  Report as requested by NASA,
>   an Atlas-Centaur designated AC 67 lifted off into a dark,
>   precipitating  stratiform overcast from launch
>   complex 36B at Cape Canaveral Air Force Station. The payload was a
>   Fleet  SatCom satellite for the US Navy.  NASA was responsible for
>   managing the launch. Just under 50 seconds  later a cloud to ground
>   lightning strike was photographed at the pad and two seconds after
>   that the vehicle  began to break up.

Learn all about lightning problems and resulting launch commit criteria [here](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110000675.pdf).

[image]

And a good Bryan O' Connor safety presentation on it [here](https://sma.nasa.gov/docs/default-source/safety-messages/safetymessage-2007-03-01-lightningstrikemishap1987-vits.pdf?sfvrsn=5ba91ef8_6) (source of the slide).

Just because it's awesome, here's a intentional rocket triggered lightning strike video (this one involved a wire).

Comment: Interesting a single error compounded into a total LOV. Hurray for modern error correcting and redundancy! Also yeah, *awesome* video

Comment: I’ll have a thorough read of that paper when I get a chance... just kidding, it’s a *monster*, but thanks nonetheless!